# Execute a custom script on Azure VM Deletion

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, terraform, azure-virtual-machine

Is it possible to execute a separate script when uninstalling the Azure VM Custom Script Extension *OR* VM Deletion than what ran during install?

Our use case:

- On Extension **Install:** Install software and add licensing (e.g. using `install.ps1`)
- On Extension **Uninstall:** Remove licensing (e.g. using `uninstall.ps1`)

We cannot find a clean way to automatically execute clean up script on extension uninstall / VM delete.

---

Below is a Terraform example used to create VM and the hilighted problem area that we cannot implement:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  skip_provider_registration = true
  features {
    virtual_machine {
      delete_os_disk_on_deletion = true
      graceful_shutdown          = true
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name     = "test-resources"
  location = "CanadaCentral"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "test" {
  name                = "test-network"
  address_space       = ["10.9.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "test" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.test.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.9.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "test" {
  name                = "test-nsg"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "AllowPSRemoting" {
  access                      = "Allow"
  destination_address_prefix  = "*"
  destination_port_range      = "5986"
  direction                   = "Inbound"
  name                        = "AllowPSRemoting"
  network_security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.test.name
  priority                    = 301
  protocol                    = "Tcp"
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  source_address_prefix       = "*"
  source_port_range           = "*"
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "test" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.test.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.test.id
}

# resource "azurerm_public_ip" "test" {
#   name                = "acceptanceTestPublicIp1"
#   resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
#   location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
#   allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
# }

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "test" {
  name                = "test-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.test.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    # public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.test.id
  }
}

locals {
  first_logon_script = <<-SCRIPT
    netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=WinRM_HTTP_5985 protocol=TCP dir=in localport=5985 action=allow
  SCRIPT

  install_script = <<-SCRIPT
    # Invoke-WebRequest -Method "POST" -Uri "https://<vendor_api>/register" -Body "..."

    $logFile = "C:\install.log"

    If (-not (Test-Path -path $logFile -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue")) {
        New-Item -Path $logFile -ItemType "File"
    }

    Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value "$(Get-Date) Ran install.ps1"
  SCRIPT

  uninstall_script = <<-SCRIPT
    # Invoke-WebRequest -Method "POST" -Uri "https://<vendor_api>/unregister" -Body "..."

    $logFile = "C:\install.log"

    If (-not (Test-Path -path $logFile -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue")) {
        New-Item -Path $logFile -ItemType "File"
    }

    Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value "$(Get-Date) Ran uninstall.ps1"
  SCRIPT
}

resource "local_file" "install_script" {
  filename = "${path.module}/install.ps1"
  content = local.install_script
}

resource "local_file" "uninstall_script" {
  filename = "${path.module}/uninstall.ps1"
  content = local.uninstall_script
}

locals {
  username = "adminuser"
  password = "P@$$w0rd1234!"
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "test" {
  name                = "test-machine"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
  size                = "Standard_F2"
  admin_username      = local.username
  admin_password      = local.password
  priority            = "Regular"
  provision_vm_agent  = true

  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.test.id,
  ]

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2016-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  ############################################################
  # Need help with this region below
  # 1. Create `install.ps1` file locally on remote Windows VM with predefined content
  # 2. Create `uninstall.ps1` file locally on remote Windows VM with predefined content
  # 3. Execute `install.ps1` file on VM creation
  # 4. Execute `uninstall.ps1` file on VM destroy

  winrm_listener {
    protocol = "Http"
  }

  additional_unattend_content {
    setting = "AutoLogon"
    content = "<AutoLogon><Password><Value>${local.username}</Value></Password><Enabled>true</Enabled><LogonCount>1</LogonCount><Username>${local.password}</Username></AutoLogon>"
  }

  additional_unattend_content {
    setting = "FirstLogonCommands"
    content = "<FirstLogonCommands><SynchronousCommand><CommandLine>${local.first_logon_script}</CommandLine><Order>1</Order></SynchronousCommand></FirstLogonCommands>"
  }

  # Connection used by `file` and `remote-exec` provisioners
  connection {
    host     = self.private_ip_address
    type     = "winrm"
    user     = self.admin_username
    password = self.admin_password
    timeout  = "5m"
    https    = false
    port     = "5985"
    insecure = true
  }

  # Copy install file during creation
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = local_file.install_script.filename
    destination = "C:/install.txt"
    when        = create
  }

  # Run uninstall file during creation
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    when   = create
    script = "C:/install.ps1"
  }

  # Copy uninstall file during creation
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = local_file.uninstall_script.filename
    destination = "C:/uninstall.txt"
    when        = create
  }

  # Run uninstall file during destruction
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    when   = destroy
    script = "C:/uninstall.ps1"
  }

  # Need help with above section
  ############################################################
}
```

Currently seeing this error:

```sh
timeout - last error: http response error: 401 - invalid content type
```

This is similar to question: [Terraform File Provisioner to Upload to Azure VM Using WinRM: Error: i/o timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62224835/terraform-file-provisioner-to-upload-to-azure-vm-using-winrm-error-i-o-timeout)

However, unlike that question, we don't need HTTPS yet. Even HTTP is showing the same error.

Terraform version details:

```sh
Terraform v1.0.9
on windows_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.82.0
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with ScriptA.ps1 so that i can test in my environment according to your question and what is point of saying /VM delete over here please explain ?

Comment: "ScriptA.ps1" is a place holder as we have proprietary code that we cannot share. Having ScriptA.ps1 is not as important either.  

If you want to test in your environment, then a simple PowerShell script to create "FileA.txt" would be good enough. Then uninstalling the VM extension can execute "ScriptB.ps1" that will create "FileB.txt"

Comment: It is usually not necessary to include proprietary code. Please update your question after reading this link. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: For @RahulKumarShaw-MT, I've added a fully example of creating an Azure VM with some distinct install versus uninstall script as example.